# SD CARD ON UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I bought an SD card for my Ubuntu computer to increase the amount of storage capacity. However, the SD card does not increase the capacity of my computer. I want to increase the storage capacity so that I can install Steam.

Answer (score 0):

Just plugging an SD card into a computer isn't going to magically increase the size of the root file system (unless it is in RAID 0 (or some combination of RAID 0)). This doesn't mean that you can't still use the SD card to store things on your computer, however. You need to move some of your files (such as documents, videos, pictures, etc.) to the SD card. You can see how to do this here.

You cannot install Steam to any drive other than your root hard drive.

Comment: Just a thought but he could mount the SD card and create a Steam folder with a symbolic link to `~/.local/share/Steam` which will increase the amount of space for Steam as it would install on the SD card and not in the home directory.

Comment: Huh, you're right, but that probably wouldn't be the _best_ idea because those suckers are terrible for write cycles.

Comment: ye, I wouldn't recommend using an SD Card for active storage unless you absolutely have to (in the case of the Raspberry Pi and such) but on a regular desktop/laptop? Upgrading an SDD/HDD will provide a greater increase in performance and it is fairly cheap and easy.